# Best way to handle a POST/PUT request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working with an API that accepts GET, POST and PUT methods and I am trying to figure out how I can determine my app to use either POST or PUT. Let me explain:

I have a form with two inputs. First input gets a param from the URL, then based on that, I will do a GET request to retrieve some data. Also, I'm also populating the second input with some number I get from that API call.

Now, whilst the first input is readonly, the second input is editable, and therefore we can  do a POST/PUT request on form submission. The problem is, I really don't know how to create the logic on which there will be determined if it's a POST or a PUT request.

In theory, you would do a POST to add a completely new entry, and PUT to update an existing entry. But how exactly do we determine which one will be used? Like, do we check if the state is populated with data and then we add PUT as the method argument to the fetch options?

I have also created this Sandbox (using a mock API) to illustrate a practical example of the explanation above.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-flower-n3dxh2

Answer (score 2):

It's always `PUT` in your case, because you are modifying an existing item, and not creating one (`POST`).

You'd probably want to not allow the user to submit if the field hasn't been changed at all. That would be both informative to the user and also save HTTP requests.

Comment: I have changed the line `setUrl(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200));` so that it's not always PUT, just to illustrate my example a bit better.

Comment: I don't understand, when do you think it would not be `PUT`? When `setUrl(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200));` returns which value?